# How do I use groupBy $filter within another $filter in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to group a list within a filter in angular and basically need to inject the filter into another filter. I'm aware of how to use the groupFilter within a template but am confused as to how to use the filter within another filter.

This is my code:

```
var myFilters = angular.module('myFilters', ['angular.filter']);

myFilters.filter('sortColumn', [ '$filter', function( $filter ) {
  return function(input, rules) {
    var list = [], cutList = [], projectedCutList = [], nullList = [];
    ....

    var groupedList = $filter('groupBy')(input, 'Status');
    console.debug('groupedList', groupedList);
  };
}]);
```

this is the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=groupByFilterProvider%20%3C-%20groupByFilter
at Error (native)
```

any ideas?

Comment: `$filter('groupBy')`?

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo. Still not working unfortunately!

Comment: Error has changed though!

Comment: progress! :) That error happens when the filter is not loaded. I see it is not part of core but most likely from a separate module (https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter), did you include the source file on the page and declare a dependency on `angular.filter` for your module?

Comment: thank you! I edited my question  to show the module. If I inject the filter it comes up with a different error on load: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=leaderboardApp&p1=…p%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9002%2Fscripts%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170)

Comment: A bit harder to tell what that is to be honest. Maybe it needs v1.3. I'm not sure what that error means, sorry.